# NSArray exception when adding track to starred playlist

Tags: ios, spotify, playlist

Sometimes, I'm getting a fatal exception when trying to "star" a track in **cocoalibspotify**. I'm logging in with a user with a heavy dataset (hundreds of playlists, but < 15 starred tracks).

This is how I "star" the `SPTrack`:

```
[[[[SPSession sharedSession] starredPlaylist] items] addObject:myTrack];
```

... and the stack trace:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectsAtIndexes:]: index 12 beyond bounds [0 .. 11]'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01e125a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x021a1313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01da0f99 -[NSArray objectsAtIndexes:] + 633
    3   Foundation                          0x016a250b -[NSKeyValueArray objectsAtIndexes:] + 110
    4   Foundation                          0x016aaca6 NSKeyValueDidChangeByArrayMutation + 103
    5   Foundation                          0x01610c30 NSKeyValueDidChange + 266
    6   Foundation                          0x016aba95 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:] + 123
    7   Foundation                          0x016a4d0e -[NSKeyValueNotifyingMutableArray addObject:] + 239
    8   MyApp                               0x000922cd -[PlaylistManager starTrack:] + 285
    ...
```

This only seems to happen within a minute or two after logging in (i.e. user data is loaded), so I'm guessing it might be an issue where the data isn't fully loaded or something?

I've tried to find out if there's any properties to observe in order to find out when everything's fully loaded. But as the array might be empty (and the user might not have starred any tracks before), it seems like there's no good way of validating that everything's loaded...?  The `loaded` property of `SPPlaylist` seems to refer to the playlist metadata, and not its tracks (?).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show me the code of where you instantiate the array 'items'?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it again. It looks like there is an instance of NSArray that is observing the NSMutable array. And it's that NSArray that is generating the error. Not the NSMutableArray.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's what's going on inside the `cocoalibspotify` library, which is the lib handling the change (and which this issue relates to). Check out `SPPlaylist.m` in https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/tree/master/common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the So it looks like you're not supposed to manipulate that array directly. Instead call `[myTrack setStarred:YES];`

Basically, I just went through the entire Spotify API for you to find that answer.

Comment: You know, you're actually right! Well done! I figured I had to do it the other way around, as that's how tracks are added to playlists in other situations. I'd seen the `-setStarred:` method, but ignored it for that exact reason... Sometimes you just need someone else to point to the answer in front of you. :) 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A full code sample for this:

```
-(void)starTrack:(NSString *)uri {

NSURL *trackURL = [NSURL URLWithString:uri];

[[SPSession sharedSession] trackForURL:trackURL callback:^(SPTrack *track) {

    if (track != nil) {

        [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:track timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *tracks, NSArray *notLoadedTracks) {

            [track setStarred:YES];

        }];
    }
}];
```

}